# Непонятый TypeError

Tags: python

```
mainicon = re.findall(r'<img src="(.*)" alt="Group Icon"', accs[i][0])

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Точно знаю, что accs[i][0] - строка. Что его еще может не устраивать?

Comment: мб не закрытый тег?)

Comment: эм, все закрыто.
если вы про "<img" - то это лишь парсинг, оно не интерпретируется.
да и ошибки с тегами выводятся по другому

Comment: Попробуйте почитать [Python Basics][1] с пункта 6. Может у вас проблема со списком и accs[i][0] все таки не строка.


  [1]: http://www.astro.ufl.edu/~warner/prog/python.html

Comment: print(type(accs[i][0]) выдает мне, что это str. раньше подобные конструкции спокойно работали...

Comment: Лучше проверять так: <pre><code>isinstance((accs[i][0]), str)</code></pre>
Если это точно строка, то может попробовать присвоить переменной (accs[i][0]), а потом передать в функцию.

Comment: True
создал temp = accs[i][0] - та же ерунда

Comment: попробуйте accs[i,0]

Answer (score 1):

```
r'<img src="(.*)" alt="Group Icon"'
```

Попробуйте без r

```
mainicon = re.findall('<img src="(.*)" alt="Group Icon"', accs[i][0])
```

Comment: увы, не помогло...

Answer (score 0):

Может кавычки изменить, возможно у той строки, в которой вы ищете кавычки двойные, а вы ищете по одинарным и возникает ошибка двух разных типов. Попробуйте заменить все одинарные кавычки двойными и наоборот в строке-шаблоне, по которой ищете